# Any GUI non-relational database manager?

Tags: database, user-interface, yaml

Is there anything that would make it easier to manage YAML data files? I am in the process of consolidating two bookfuls of yoga poses into a personal reference. It's currently as YAML text files, but as the dataset grows, it's becoming harder to keep track of what poses I have already written down.

The poses all have some fields that need to be filled, like name and name in sanskrit. But sometimes the data is nested so I don't any relational databases would work very well.

Answer (score 1):

Not really for YAML, but [RockMongo](http://sourceforge.net/p/rockmongo/wiki/Home/) (for MongoDB) manages almost all aspects of the non relational MongoDB database, and allows for creating collections, rows, and editing data. It's a PHP web interface.